# free percent character in format string for _vsnprintf and _vsnprintf_s

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, printf

Very surprising behavior with free '%' in format string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(const char *format, ...) {
  const size_t buffSize = 1024;
  char msg[buffSize];
  {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    _vsnprintf(msg, buffSize, format, args);
    va_end(args);
    std::cout << msg << std::endl; // here you get a,b,,c,d,e
  }
  {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    _vsnprintf_s(msg, buffSize, format, args); // and here you crash and burn
    va_end(args);
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
  }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR *argv[]) {
  foo("%s,b,%,c,d,%s", "a", "e");
  return 0;
}
```

It is not what you expect to get, especially when the following [is stated by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> If a percent sign is followed by a character that has no meaning as a
>   format field, the character is copied to the output unchanged.

So what we see here? A bug? since when? was it fixed for msvc12/13?

EDIT01:
Ok, I misread the statement, lets focus on crash

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(const char *format, ...) {
  const size_t buffSize = 1024;
  char msg[buffSize];
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, format);
  _vsnprintf_s(msg, buffSize, format, args);
  va_end(args);
  std::cout << msg << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  foo("b,%,c,d"); // crash here
  foo("%s,b,%,c,d,%s", "a", "e"); // there and everywhere
  return 0;
}
```

EDIT02:
Got an answer from Microsoft Connect

> Thanks for contacting Microsoft about this issue. We've found that we
>   left out important information about how the secure functions behave
>   from the Format Specification Syntax page. The secure functions do
>   additional validation of the format string, and invoke the invalid
>   parameter handler if an unexpected character follows the initial %
>   character. By default, this terminates the program with a Dr. Watson
>   report. In Debug mode, it causes an assert first. More information is
>   available in the Parameter Validation topic at
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksazx244.aspx . The Format
>   Specification Syntax page is being updated with this information.
>   Expect to see the updated page for Visual Studio 2013 in the next week
>   or so.

Comment: What's the problem? The character (`','`) *is* copied to the output unchanged. If you want to print an actual percent sign, double it up: `"%%"`. Dunno about the crash though. Not sure you can reuse the argument list like that.

Comment: Darn! I misread the statement... And what about the secured function crash? Ideas?

Comment: If you want a `%` to appear reliably in the output, use `%%` in the format string.  The `%,c` string could be interpreted as `%c` with an unknown modifier (flag); that might mean that the `%s` at the end is reading garbage, and then crashing.  Don't rely on undefined behaviour.

Comment: It crashes even when you don't reuse it

Comment: @JonathanLeffler as for your first comment - how do you manage your double percent escaping when the format string is a free runtime string, provided by the user for example, and no, I dont want to build format validator :) Can you elaborate on your second comment?

Comment: If the format string comes from the user, you're sunk.  You either have to trust them to get it right (which requires that your users are programmers and well-informed ones at that) or you have to accept or workaround crashes.  Or you have to validate the format string.

Comment: As to what was once my 'second comment', ... I can't find the information at MSDN, so I must be confusing it with the `*scanf_s()` family of functions which does have that requirement.  I double-checked with Annex K of the ISO standard and I was clearly wrong.  So ignore that -- in fact, I've deleted 'my second comment' as it was erroneous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in fact a documentation bug. A correction should appear soon (give it a day or two) in the [Format Specification Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc.aspx) topic. The missing information is that the secure versions of the formatting functions (the ones with a trailing **_s**) do additional validation of the formatting string, and they reject a percent character followed by an unexpected character. They then invoke the invalid parameter handler in cases like this one, while the non-secure versions don't. By default, that will terminate the program and call the Dr. Watson reporting mechanism.

If you're trying to handle arbitrary format string issues, you can set the invalid parameter handler yourself with a call to [_set_invalid_parameter_handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9yf33zb.aspx) to trap cases like this, and prevent a crash. In DEBUG builds, this format string should cause an invalid parameter assertion. The [Parameter Validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksazx244.aspx) topic under [Security Features in the CRT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ef0s5kh.aspx) has more information.

Comment: Actually, I filled a bug in MS Connect. Lets wait and see what happens next